# Data Recovery option not available in Illustrator CC

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I'm using Illustrator CC v. 17.0.0 on Windows 8.1

For whatever reason my version of Illustrator doesn't even display the data recovery section. Of course this a feature I really want. If I google image search "illustrator cc data recovery" you can see that this feature is missing in my application.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your version of Illustrator does not support that feature.

> With the 2015 release of Illustrator CC, you can recover your work if Illustrator crashes and you have forgotten to save.

[Adobe, Recover files in Illustrator](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/recover-files.html)

You need to update to at least CC 2015 (19.0.0).

Comment: Thanks AndrewH! For whatever reason I thought I was using the latest version.